# How can I set the message-converters and resource-mapping in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot

I want to replace my spring web application to the version of using spring boot and also have web-app directory that is different from the normal. 
(src/main/webapp -> src/main/othernames)

Before :It has the servlet context configuration of the default servlet.

```
   <annotation-driven>
        <message-converters>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                <beans:property name="objectMapper">
                    <beans:bean class="com.knappsack.swagger4springweb.util.ScalaObjectMapper"/>
                </beans:property>
            </beans:bean>
        </message-converters>
    </annotation-driven>
    <default-servlet-handler/>

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
```

I had to do add some other things in addition to following default explanation in spring boot web application sample like the followings.

First I added tomcat embeded servlet container.

```
public class MyEmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer implements
EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

    private static final Logger LOG =
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyEmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer.class);

    @Value("${servlet.container.maxThreads}")
    private int MAX_THREADS;

     @Override
      public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer factory) {
        if(factory instanceof TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
          customizeTomcat((TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) factory);
        }
      }

      public void customizeTomcat(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory) {
        factory.addConnectorCustomizers(new TomcatConnectorCustomizer() {
          @Override
          public void customize(Connector connector) {
            Object defaultMaxThreads = connector.getAttribute("maxThreads");
            connector.setAttribute("maxThreads", MAX_THREADS);
            LOG.info("Changed Tomcat connector maxThreads from " +
                defaultMaxThreads + " to " + MAX_THREADS);
          }
        });
      }

}
```

@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

```
    if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/resources/swagger-ui/**")) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("src/main/webapp/resources/swagger-ui/**").addResourceLocations(
                "classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```

Second, I added the class for additional configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

I replaced the configuration in XML file to the spring boot one. But I can't do it perfectly. How can I configure for resource-mapping and others?

```
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved like the followings.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }



    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(
            List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    }


    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

}
```